# Correct version of Spring and Hibernate and required dependencies...Exception due to dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Since three days i am trying to get my Spring-Hibernate programs run. i had really tough time finding the involved dependencies due to version difference between hibernate2 and hibernate3.
Finally i was able to run program with following set of dependencies

- cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
- commons-collections.jar
- commons-dbcp.jar
- commons-pool.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- dom4j-1.4.jar
- ehcache-1.6.0-beta1.jar
- hibernate-3.1.3.jar
- hsqldb.jar
- jta.jar log4j-1.2.9.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
- org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.M1.jar
- org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.M1.jar
- spring-2.5.6.jar
- spring-beans-2.0.4.jar

now after two days of efforts when i was able to manage the above mentioned dependencies i tried building similar program but it is throwing following error.I tried online for solution but the solution which i found there is not correct version of spring and hibernate ...Can any one tell me correct cause of exception and also correct version of the Spring and hibernate

---

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRecordDAO' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

---

I am also adding my application context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/subhash"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>MyRecord.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
         </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory"><ref local="sessionFactory"/></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="myRecordDAO" class="com.shoesobjects.MyRecordDAOHibernateWithSpring">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate"><ref local="hibernateTemplate"/></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a)

> **Note**
>   As of Spring 3.0, Spring requires **Hibernate 3.2 or later**.

**Source:**

- [Spring 3.1.x Reference >
  Hibernate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate)

b)

> - org.springframework.orm-**3.1.0.M1**.jar
> - org.springframework.transaction-**3.1.0.M1**.jar
> - spring-**2.5.6**.jar
> - spring-beans-**2.0.4**.jar

Do you really think mixing current pre-release versions (3.1.x) with ancient versions (2.0.4 was released in 2007) is a good idea?

---

As [matt says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326051/correct-version-of-spring-and-hibernate-and-required-dependencies-exception-due/5326154#5326154): use a dependency managements system like Maven, what you are dealing with is jar hell. Here's an article about referencing Spring 3.x artifacts from maven:

> **[Obtaining Spring 3 Artifacts with
>   Maven](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/)**

Comment: hi sean 
thanks for your quick response and the useful link i am going through this link but i am a newbie and just configured a simple program i want to know why i need these dependencies what is the criteria for choosing these dependencies.
How to know which dependency is required and which is not.

Comment: @Anupam there's no easy answer, I'm afraid. You need to develop an understanding of many different technologies and their workings together. Tutorials like [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/) can help but are almost always outdated. I'd suggest to stick with the current Spring Release version 3.0.x and study their [hibernate reference and samples](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate)

Comment: Thanks Sean ... let me do this homework and 'll also study about maven... i hope that will make my situation little better.......any idea about the exception i mentioned above?

Comment: @Anupam your config looks ok, I'm guessing you have issues with the different version. remove all spring* and org.springframework* jars, download [the latest release version](http://www.springsource.com/download/community) and just put all spring jars from that version on the classpath. that should get you up'n'running until you have more time to actually sort things out

Comment: ..thanks a lot your guidance helped me a lot now every thing is working smoothly.. now i know what dependencies are required and why we need them.version mismatch was the evil!!!!!

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Please help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694173/missing-contextloaderlistener-class-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a dependency management tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) so you don't have to handle sorting through the dependencies and required versions on your own.

- [Hibernate docs on using with Maven](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-mvn)

Comment: Hi matt thanks for the response and the provided link...i will learn the dependency management but before learning that i want to learn what is the minimum set required and what is the role of each dependency...can you plz suggest me a link where i can know the flow of basic spring-hibernate integration program and which dependency is playing what role

Answer (score 1):

Got my problem resolved ...As pointed by Sean it was due to mixing different versions of spring and hibernate. Message for other newbies is please use latest version of spring and hibernate.As of Spring 3.0, Spring requires Hibernate 3.2 or later.one should never mix old and new version.

Comment: nice in sending message to other newbies :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple file that worked for me, I used transaction manager and not template.

```
<bean id="mySqlDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stackoverflow" />
            <property name="user" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="******" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource" />
            <property name="mappingResources">
                    <list>
                            <value>Post.hbm.xml</value>
                            <value>Tag.hbm.xml</value>
                            <value>User.hbm.xml</value>
                    </list>
            </property>

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                    <value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
                    </value>
                    <!--
                            hibernate.connection.provider_class =
                            org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
                            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
                            hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
                    -->
            </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
            <!--
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource"/>
            -->
    </bean>
```

Also, I think the hibernate download package comes with separate folders that indicate what its specific dependencies are. As for the interrelation between hibernate and spring, I think you will have to use some dependency management tool as others have suggested.  I do not think maven is a convenient tool. Just don't ever depart from maven's expected project structure and you should be fine.